# How add new fields in registration form Opencart 3

Tags: php, field, opencart, registration

Hello I want to add more required fields in my user registration form like( phone number, mobile number , Country, Town, address)

Answer (score 0):

In admin panel go to *Customer > Custom Field*

Here you can add any custom field you want. Just check **Required** before saving new field, and enable it. After that you will see it in your registration page.